# Kitchen Cabinet Concern

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

I have a company that has already made some big mistake with my kitchen remodel.They are almost done with the cabinets and I found little plastic squares underneath the bottom of the cabinets. This concerns me because it does not look professional and I am wondering if it is normal for cabinets to sit on this. I also noticed some have them and some don’t.

Comment: Got pics of these plastic squares?

Answer (score 1):

They are packing because the cabinets need to be level to support the worksurface.

The floor is not level and there are two solutions:

1. level the floor before fitting the cabinets,
2. level the cabinets - often they have adjustable feet for this.

Do NOT remove the packing they have  fitted.